# In jquery draggable modal window how to prevent drag when scroll is done on table within draggable

Tags: jquery, scroll, draggable, modal-dialog

I have jquery modal window which is draggable. There is table inside window which has overflow-y set to true. When I scroll the table the window is getting dragged - how do I prevent drag on scroll operation. This is sample code.

```
 <div id="container">
<table style="overflow-y:auto;"> </table>
</div>

$('#container').draggable();
```

On scroll event on table how do I prevent drag on window? Can someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQueryUI dialog box.  I have scrollable content in my dialogs and it works great.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

**edit**

however, perhaps it's because you are checking for a mouse down anywhere within the dialog box which then triggers the move.

You will want to ensure that the drag event only triggers on say the title of the dialog.

```
 <div id="container">
 <div style=""height:30px" id="title">this is the title</div>
<table style="overflow-y:auto;"> </table>
</div>

$('#title').click(function(){$('#container').draggable();})
```

**edit 2**

```
$("#container").click(
  function(){
    if ($(this).tagName == "div")
      $(this).draggable();
  }
);
```

Untested but the intent should be clear

Comment: Thanks Greigs. I can solve the problem by restricting drag to trigger only on title (using handle option of draggable). But I need window to be draggable from anywhere on dialog except when doing scroll operation on table. Any suggestions?

Comment: With first edit I a restricted to drag only from title window. How can I drag from anywhere in window (except scroll on table?)

Answer (score 0):

Use *cancel* property from *jQuery UI draggable*:

```
<div id="container">
    <table style="overflow-y:auto;" id="tableID"> </table>
</div>

$(".container").draggable({
    cancel : ".tableID"
});
```